# Identifying the IP,PORT and Instance of a SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to connect to SQL server instance in a remote system(a VPN has been set up between my machine and the server). The IP address I am supposed to connect to is 192.168.1.X, which I can ping from my machine.
When I RDP into the server hosting the SQL server and run in Sql server studio:

> > USE master GO xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', 'any', NULL, NULL, N'asc'  GO

I get the following:
LogDate                ProcessInfo        Text
2016-03-05 12:21:37.630 Server  Server is listening on [ 'any'  12345],
2016-03-05 12:21:37.630 Server  Server is listening on [ 'any'  12345].

Question 1: Does this mean that the server is listening to any queries  in ipv6 and ipv4 IP for the port 12345?

Question 2: When I check the SQL TCP/IP setting in the host server, I see that the ipv6 IP is 127.0.0.Y. Should it not be 192.168.1.X? How do I find out what it the IP I am supposed to connect to?

[TCP Dynamic ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ACo6.jpg)

Comment: VPNs translate addresses from one network to another. `127.0.0.1` on the other hand is the *home* address by which each machine refers to itself. Have you tried connecting to the repote database server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to connect to the remote DB. I was told after the VPN was set to 192.168.1.X(Which i can ping from my m/c). I was told the port was 62648. I can not connect to either 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.X via sql studio.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't pinging a machine in your own network? Did you specify the port in the connection dialog? Trying to connect to the 127 address is pointless - that's **the local** computer's address.

Comment: Right, did not think about that.I will check that out and get back to you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks! That was the case it seems,VPN needs to be sorted out. Sorry for being stupid. So to answer my own questions: 1. Yes it does 2.The local ip after the VPN is set up is the IP I need to connect to. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP into the server, and then run the SQL Configuration Manager. Open up SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (or whatever version it is if not 11) and select Client Protocols under it. In the right-hand pan el, select TCP/IP, right-click it and select Properties.

[image]

You can see that it shows the port it's ljstening on (1433 here, which is the default). If the port is not 1433 you can sepcify it in the connection string as `Data Source=servername,portnumber` e.g.`Data Source=MyServerName,12345` (if 12345 is the port).

BTW, check that TCP/IP is enabled: if it's not then the port doesn't really matter!

Comment: I added a screen grab and it says 1433, but when I look at Protocol for SQLExpress , TCP Dynamic ports says; 12345. I was wondering if in the TCP/IP properties the the IP4 IP(127.0.0.X) address should be the one I should be connection to? but when I do a IPconfig on the server the IP4 IP is 192.168.1.X.

Comment: SQLExpress will be listening on a different port to SQLServer. Which one you use depends on whether you're using SQLServer or SQLExpress - I can't tell you that :) The IP/Servername to use in the connection string is probably whatever you use to identify the target machine to RDP.